# Regex not working in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Parsing emails, as they can be tricky with all of their fields, I have a dynamic mapping that states

```
"dynamic_templates" : [{
                        "string_fields" : {
                            "mapping" : {
                                        "index" : "not_analyzed",
                                        "ignore_above" : 256,
                                        "type" : "string"
                            },
                            "match_mapping_type" : "string",
                            "match" : "*"
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

which is working fine. But, I have a field: headers.x-mailer that is using the above mapping. Querying Kibana for:

```
header.x-mailer:/PHPMailer.+/
```

only returns values that are lowercase. This should not be, as it is "not_analyzed"

This doesnt work either:

```
header.x-mailer:PHPMailer*
```

But this does (but returns both upper and lower, of course):

```
header.x-mailer:*ailer*
```

I need to be able to do Case Sensitive queries in kibana for "not_analyzed" fields. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What are you using? K3 or K4?

Comment: k4, it seems that my regex curl works, and found that maybe perhaps k4 is only using regexp on _all?

Comment: I think the problem is with the option `lowercase_expanded_terms`. Could you try to execute the exact query Kibana is doing with CURL and set `lowercase_expanded_terms` to `false`? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Comment: yep, it works that way, how do i turn off this? (Nevermind, I will find this :D  Thanks for your help ! )

Comment: In settings, there is an option to set parameters for queryStrings (not 100% sure, I cannot access to K4 right now, but I think it is the first one). The only problem is that this behaviour will be set for all the queries you do (maybe it's what you want for your use case).